# How do I convert this string into json with javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, regex, string, parsing

How do I parse string into json with javascript?

"[{'Name': \"O'BRIEN DEIRDRE\", 'Text': 'Hello'}]"

I need to change all single quote to double quote, but I need to keep the single quote of O'BRIEN

Comment: If at all possible, it would be better to fix whatever is generating that malformed json instead.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe this can fix your problem: https://regexr.com/55t8o

Edit:
If the link is deprecated the regex expression should be '([a-zA-Z]*)' and replace it with "$1"

I also agree with Taplar who commented that it would probably be better if you found out why it's using ' instead of " and not use regex. Hope this helps

Comment: It's a regex expression that fixes your problem unless I'm misunderstanding you question

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/26293339)

Comment: @HarshalParekh Thanks for the heads up love the feedback I have changed the answer hope this is better